# Placing spans on opposite sides of div, without using float

Tags: html, css

I have some spans inside of a div. I would like one span, which contains some string, on the left side and one span which contains some font awesome icons on the right side. However I cannot use floats as these elements are heavily nested and that causes issues. Note also the width is finite and sometimes if the string is long enough it can word break.

```
<div>
<span>Some Long Text Here</span>
<span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to guarantee the spacing, you can use flexbox or float (float will not mess up "heavily nested" elements as you say..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an option use `flexbox` :

```css
div {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background: purple;
  /*Code flex*/
  display: flex;
}

span:first-child {
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <span>Some Long Text Here</span>
  <span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
</div><br>
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo quibusdam, iusto laboriosam ipsam quas impedit voluptatem fugiat rerum quis, minima velit nam accusantium beatae voluptas commodi eligendi molestiae dolorum reiciendis!</span>
  <span><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
</div>
```